# How to get List of results from Hibernate Session by a List of Keys\ids?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, collections, criteria

I have a list objects that have EmbeddedIds:

```
PKtype implements Serializable
{
    String a;
    String b;
}

MyObject
{
    PKtype pk;
    String something;
}

List<MyObject> myList;
```

this list was loaded from some files.

Now i need to save, in case it is new, or merge, in case it is in session or in DB, each of them.

If object had a `Long id;`, or any other single identifying property, it would be simple has doing

```
List<MyObject> objs = session.createCriteria(MyObject.class).add(Restrictions.in("id", ids)).list();
```

Instead, currently there's a cicle going through all of them and doing one at a time:

```
for(MyObject obj : objsFromFile)
{
    MyObject bdObject = session.get(MyObject.class, obj.getPk());
    //do stuff
}
```

so that if it exists it makes a `merge` else its a `save`. (i will not discuss here why I'm not using update\saveorupdate)

But as there are `X(in order of the thousands) * N(1...5)` number of them in the files, all these `gets` are making execution take hours to process.

I need something like `Session.get(MyObject.class, List<PKtype> keys)` and get 20 by 20 or 100 by 100, depending on the number of `keys` i decide to process each time.

But i cant find any of sorts in the `Session`. Am I missing something? An `EmbeddedId` cant be used like this? How can i solve this?